# How can I terminate an ASP.NET application on IIS following an unrecoverable error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, error-handling

Supopse I have a unhandled exception (or a known serious, unrecoverable error). The scariest situation is a security breach, but it could apply to anything that means my state is so badly hosed I can't expect to continue safely.

What do I do?

In a traditional application, the usual technique is to end my process, quickly. as soon as possible. I'm calling Process.Exit, TerminateProcess, die, or whatever other tool the environment has that means "END. NOW". [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/23/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-eight-more-exceptions.aspx) expresses the reasoning for this attitude well.

In a production ASP.NET application running on IIS, it's not so simple. I can certainly end the current process and cough an error to the event log or wherever. That's essentially what happens with any unhandled exception. But the next time a request comes in, IIS is just going to spin up a new worker process. If my fatal error was a transient problem that's great.

But if my problem persists past the lifetime of my process, the new one won't be any better. It could even be compounded by the intialization code or a reattempt. Plus, if IIS is running multiple worker processes within the same application pool, even killing my process doesn't kill the application. Logically speaking all those other workers may be hosed too and just not know it yet.

So far I've only come up with two options.

- End the process and hope for the best. Knowing that the app will just be restarted, this is pretty much the same as "catch(Exception) {}". Hardly satisfying.
- "Reaching out" to tell IIS to disable the app, stop IIS, the machine, etc. This seems like a brutal hack. Moreover I'd guess it's likely to require elevated security credentials. During termination of a possibly-compromised process seems like a poor time to have those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think of are something as following:

1. You can go ahead use the advanced setting of an Application Pool in IIS named **"Rapid-Fail protection"**, set the **Failure Interval** long enough as you like, and make the **Maximum Failures** as 1, then go ahead thrown the exception and make the IIS think this application pool can't work correctly so that it will send back **Service Unavailable** to client side or even reset the connection(depend on your setting). For more detail please check it here: [Failure Settings for an Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure) . However you need to be very careful to not overkill, I mean you need to write a very good application that all exception been handled properly and only the one you want to terminate application can really been detected by IIS, otherwise maybe a single user click just brought down your site.
2. Another solution is just go ahead make it your own code, I mean you can record such an error in some certain way like creating a file named **SystemCrashed**, and then terminate the Application, then check if file exist on **Application_Startup** and do nothing but terminate the Application if file been found. Something like a lock. This need more code but maybe safer than IIS settings, I mean there can't be too much overkill as long as you get it right to remove the lock.

Comment: Something similar to option 2 is already present in the Framework.  Drop an app_offline.htm file into your application root to take it offline immediately.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx for more info.

Comment: First time heard that hidden feature which looks cool, however seems can't working well and need more tricks with MVC: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/app_offlinehtm-gotchas-with-aspnet-mvc Btw I'm just afraid of using those undocumented stuff as any further patch may just make it not working. I personally think it should be good enough for maintenance but not that reliable for some function needed here.